# my ncurses window isn't appearing on my terminal

Tags: c++, ncurses

I'm new to Ncurses and I tried to make a program in C++ that makes a window then displays a box and text on both the box and standard screen.

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ncurses.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    initscr();
    int h,w,y,x;
    h = 10;
    w = 25;
    y = 15;
    x = 20;
    WINDOW * win = newwin(h ,w, y, x);
    box(win,0,0);
    wrefresh(win);
    printw("Hello");
    wprintw(win,"hi");
    wrefresh(win);
    getch();
    refresh();
    endwin();
    
    return 0;
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that the problem is with the window's position (y and x coordinates). Set `y=0` and `x=0` to position the window in the upper-left corner of the screen and see if it appears.

You can also check if ncurses is properly initialised by adding `if (!initscr()) endwin(); return 1;}` at the beginning of the `main` function to ensure that ncurses has been successfully initialised.

The updated code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ncurses.h>

int main() {
  if (!initscr()) {
    endwin();
    return 1;
  }

  int h = 10, w = 25, y = 0, x = 0;
  WINDOW *win = newwin(h, w, y, x);

  box(win, 0, 0);
  wrefresh(win);
  printw("Hello");
  wprintw(win, "hi");
  wrefresh(win);
  getch();
  refresh();
  endwin();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping but on my terminal my window still doesn't appear.

Comment: Hi @popsicle7 I have revised my answer. Can you please try again?

Comment: It still doesn't work for me..

Comment: The code should work.

Are you typing `clear` before running `ncurses` in the terminal, followed by the name of your code file?

Can you list out the steps so I can try to reproduce what you are doing?

Comment: Oops nevermind your're right I just forgot to type clear. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome @popsicle7

Do you think I should update the answer to say that you should always type "clear" before running ncurses?

Comment: Well I don't know because I've seen most people run their ncurses program just fine.I'm not sure with or without but i'd probably leave it how it is.